# Surface Area and Volume of a cylinder

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, functions, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have the question following, but I'm lost where to start off with. Could anyone guide me through, or give me few step hints with an answer so I can some how work backwards on the question? Thanks!

- A storage tank is to be constructed in the shape of a cylinder such that the ratio of the radius, r, to the height of the tank is 1:3.

  - Write a polynomial function to represent the surface area of the tank in terms of r, and the volume of the tank in terms of r

[image]

$$SA=2πrh+2πr^2$$
$$V=πr^2h$$

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You have that $\frac{r}{h}=\frac{1}{3}$ Therefore $h=3r$. Now just plug this in the expressions for $SA$ and $V$.

Comment: Is it that simple!? Like this? $SA= 2πr(3r) + 2πr^2$ and $V = πr^2(3r)$ @Svetoslav

Comment: Yes, it is that simple :)